# Populate rows of empty matrix from another matrix by index array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array:

```
arr = np.array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
                [ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2],
                [ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2]])
```

and an index array:

```
index_arr = np.array([True, False, False, True, True])
```

and an empty matrix of zeros:

```
output = np.array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
                   [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Is there a way that I can  combine these using numpy functions/indexing tricks such that the rows of my array replace the rows in the zero matrix according to the index array? That is, I would end up with this as my final output

```
>>> array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
           [ 0.,   0.,   0.,   0. ],
           [ 0.,   0.,   0.,   0. ],
           [ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2],
           [ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2]])
```

If it's not clear what I want to do here: the two middle rows of the output are empty because the second and third entry in `index_arr` are `False`. The first row of the `arr` is copied into the first row of the output, and the final two rows of the `arr` are copied into the final two rows of the output, as to line up with the `True` values in `index_arr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use logical vector indexing for subsetting and assignment:

```
output[index_arr] = arr

#array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
#       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
#       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
#       [ 4.6,  3.1,  1.5,  0.2],
#       [ 5. ,  3.6,  1.4,  0.2]])
```